# Discord.js SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier (For command handler)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I'm creating a discord bot for utility in discord.js
The command handler requires commands in different js files.
Here's the code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Ping command'
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send('Pong!');
    }
};
```

So, here's my error:

```
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780191+00:00 app[Worker.1]: /app/commands/ping.js:4
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780229+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     execute(message, args) {
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780229+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     ^^^^^^^
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780229+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780230+00:00 app[Worker.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780231+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780231+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780232+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780232+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780232+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780233+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780233+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780233+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:18:19)
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780234+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
2020-09-12T12:09:58.780234+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are missing a comma after the `'Ping Command'` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you didn't put a comma after the `description` property :p

```js
name: 'ping',
description: 'Ping command', // comma :)
execute(message, args) {
 message.channel.send('Pong!');
};
```